# Bootstrap 3.x and Megmenus?

Tags: 7, theming

Has anyone found a way to get megamenus working in a Bootstrap 3.x sub theme?  I have tried the various modules, plus patches to them and ports of them, with no success.  I've mostly looked at TB Megamenu, but it does not seem to be the way to go.

At this point I am tempted to just hardcode the HTML into my template(s).

Thanks,

Eric